# Unfound resource for FlatFileItemReader after moving the file

Tags: java, csv, spring-batch, flatfilereader

I am using Spring Batch to read from a CSV file and write the lines on the screen.
My job is composed of 3 parts:
Part 1 : Verify if the CSV file exists in some INPUT directory on my disk, if it returns TRUE the file will be moved to another directory called PROD.
Part 2 : Extract data from the CSV file using FlatFileItemReader.
Part 3 : Write the all the items to the screen.

The problem is the FlatFileItemReader throws `org.springframework.batch.item.ItemStreamException: Failed to initialize the reader` caused by `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Input resource must be set`

Here is my code:

```
@Bean
public FlatFileItemReader<UniversInvestissement> reader() {
    FlatFileItemReader<UniversInvestissement> reader = new FlatFileItemReader<>();
    File csvFile = new File("C://INPUT/data.csv");
    Resource resource = resourceLoader.getResource("file:" + csvFile.getAbsolutePath());
    reader.setLinesToSkip(1);
    reader.setResource(resource);
    DefaultLineMapper lineMapper = new DefaultLineMapper();

    DelimitedLineTokenizer tokenizer = new DelimitedLineTokenizer();
    tokenizer.setNames(new String[]{"COL1", "COL2", "COL3", "COL4"});
    tokenizer.setDelimiter(";");

    FieldSetMapper fieldSetMapper = new UniversInvestissementFieldSetMapper();
    lineMapper.setLineTokenizer(tokenizer);
    lineMapper.setFieldSetMapper(fieldSetMapper);

    reader.setLineMapper(lineMapper);

    reader.setEncoding("Cp1252");
    return reader;
}

@Bean
public UniversInvestissementWriter writer() {
    return new UniversInvestissementWriter();
}

@Bean
public UniversInvestissementProcessor processor() {
    return new UniversInvestissementProcessor();
}

@Bean
public Step extractData() {
    return steps.get("extractData")
            .<UniversInvestissement, UniversInvestissementProcessorResult>chunk(1)
            .reader(reader())
            .processor(processor())
            .writer(writer())
            .build();
}
```

Actually the problem is that when the `FlatFileItemReader` is initialized it can't find the CSV file as a resource ! 
Is there a way to postpone the resource assignment and avoid this exception ?

Comment: Please note the [tag:batch-file] tag does not meaning processing many files. You can hover onto a tag to see its actual meaning.

Comment: @SteveFest, you're right. But it was suggested automatically so I picked it up I didn't knew it's not the same context ;) Thank you anyway

Comment: Thank you for replying. It's how sad to see another case of wrong "auto-correction".

Answer (score 0):

you Can use `reader.setStrict(false);`  if you set strict mode  to false the reader will **Not throw an exception** on. You might have to use `@StepScope` to make reader lazy. I am using same setup and it's working fine for me , Hope this helps you

Comment: After setting strict mode to false there is no more exception but the problem is that the reader is initialized with a null resource so it doesn't read my CSV :(

Answer (score 0):

> Verify if the CSV file exists in some INPUT directory on my disk, if
>   it returns TRUE the file will be moved to another directory called
>   PROD

This problem can easly be solved using a [`JobExecutionDecider`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.0.x/api/org/springframework/batch/core/job/flow/JobExecutionDecider.html)

```
class Checker implements JobExecutionDecider {
  FlowExecutionStatus decide(...) {
    if(<file not found in INPUT/ dir>) {
      return FlowExecutionStatus.STOPPED;
    }
    if(!<copy file from INPUT/ to PROD/ works>) {
      return FlowExecutionStatus.FAILED;
    }
    return FlowExecutionStatus.COMPLETED;
  }
}
```

Of course, `extractData()` must be changed to insert use of programmatic flow decision (check [here](http://javasampleapproach.com/spring-framework/spring-batch/spring-batch-programmatic-flow-decision) for a simple example)

Answer (score 0):

I think that problem in your `resourceLoader`, because such exception thrown by non-null assertion of resource instance. So you `resourceLoader` return null value.

Try to use `FileSystemResource` and without any resource loaders. For example:

```
reader.setResource(new FileSystemResource(csvFile));
```